# How to show a Toast message from a parent class inside the child class in android

Tags: java, android, inheritance, toast, android-toast

I have a Child class say "A" which extends a Parent class "B".

Now I want to show multiple Toast from the Parent class B in the child class A. How can I do that?

Note: Parent class B does not have a layout bound to it.

Comment: Hi Dishita, happy to help. Can you share some of your code? What is the type of class B? (e.g. what class does B extend from, if any?)

Comment: Toast does not need any layout nor even activity

Answer (score 0):

As [Marcin Orlowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235698/marcin-orlowski) mentioned in the comments, `Toast` does not need any layout nor even activity to show. More detail can refer to this [Google Developer doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#:%7E:text=A%20toast%20provides%20simple%20feedback,automatically%20disappear%20after%20a%20timeout.)

Actually we can pass `applicationContext` to `Context` param to show the `Toast` by doing this we don't rely on any `activity(layout)`

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, duration).show()
```